# How do I calculate the heat lost or gained by surroundings?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

How do I calculate the heat lost or gained by surroundings (Q surr) given mass ($m$), change in temp ($\Delta T$), and specific heat ($c$)? What equation would I use?

For example, if I do a reaction in water and have the change in temp of the water, its specific heat, and its mass, how would I calculate the heat lost/gained?

Comment: Hi Melanie. Welcome to Physics.SE. Your question looks like a formula suggestion. If it's so, a quick google would've provided you the result...

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if your chem book didn't include the formula you're looking for. If you're having a hard time making sense of the formulas you're given, could you edit the question to list what those formulas are and why you don't think they're the one you're looking for? Also try checking standard resources like Wikipedia. We're very happy to answer questions about the meanings of formulas, but if you're just asking someone to _give_ you a basic formula, that's not really the sort of question  this site is meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "heat". If you mean energy then you can calculate the energy required to cause the temperature change using the following equation: Energy = mass * specific heat capacity * temperature change (Q = mcθ).